# timestamp with jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm making a web form which uses dates in some fields and i used a jquery datepicker plugin. but in my new update they are also asking for timestamps to be recorded.

I use the below for getting the data, but i'm unable to know how to get the timestamp.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#DateRec" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "d-M" }).val(); 
});
```

The expected time and date format should be something like below.

> 04-Apr 17:03:25 (hours in 24 format, minutes, seconds)

please let me know how can i do this.

Thanks

Comment: It's a datepicker, probably you need a datetime picker?

Comment: Can you please suggest me where i can find this widget, in jqueryiu i've found only datepicker widget

Answer (score 0):

You can Adding a Timepicker to jQuery UI Datepicker by this plugin : http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a datetimepicker; you can use a widget plugin that extends datepicker functions by adding a time selection.

Project site: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Demo code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#timePicker').datetimepicker({
        controlType: 'select',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm ss'
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Ljt4T/

Comment: Hi Irvin, thanks for the solution, is there a way where in i can get the systemtime automatically instead of selecting the time?